# String was not recognized as a valid Boolean. - an Error Related to C#. GridView CheckBoxField

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, oracle11g, asp.net-4.0, odp.net

Here is the programming environment.

- Framework: ASP.NET Framework 4
- Language: Visual C# 2010
- Database: Oracle Database 11g

Here is the scenario.

I'm creating a GridView from the HR Sample Schema's HR.EMPLOYEES table. I'm trying to convert the incoming data from the COMMISSION_PCT column into a boolean value and populate the GridView with check boxes under the DataField for COMMISSION_PCT, so the employees with a value in this field will be shown with the checked check box. This is how the GridView object control looks so far.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewEmployees" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceOracle" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EMPLOYEE_ID" HeaderText="Employee ID" SortExpression="EMPLOYEE_ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FIRST_NAME" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FIRST_NAME" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LAST_NAME" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LAST_NAME" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EMAIL" HeaderText="E-mail Address" SortExpression="EMAIL" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PHONE_NUMBER" HeaderText="Phone Number" SortExpression="PHONE_NUMBER" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HIRE_DATE" HeaderText="Hire Date" SortExpression="HIRE_DATE" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="JOB_ID" HeaderText="Job ID" SortExpression="JOB_ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SALARY" HeaderText="Salary" SortExpression="SALARY" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="COMMISSION_PCT" HeaderText="Receives Commission" SortExpression="COMMISSION_PCT" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MANAGER_ID" HeaderText="Manager ID" SortExpression="MANAGER_ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DEPARTMENT_ID" HeaderText="Department ID" SortExpression="DEPARTMENT_ID" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Of course, when I try to preview the page as it is, I'll get the following error message:

## Server Error in '/' Application.

---

### *String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.*

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

**Source Error:**

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.]
...

[HttpException (0x80004005): The data in the CheckBoxField 'COMMISSION_PCT' could not be parsed as a boolean value.  Try using a BoundField instead.]
...
```

So far, I thought about using DECODE for the SQL statement, but that would still return a string value. Unfortunately, with the C# encompassing strong typing programming discipline and Oracle not supporting the boolean data type in SQL statements, it seems that I'll need to make this transition with the code behind. Got any suggestions on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behind the scenes, I'd guess [Boolean.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.parse.aspx) is being called which expects a string like "false".  If that's the case decode or a case statement should work:

```
select decode(commission_pct,0,"false", "true") as has_commission
from your_table
```

This example worked for me:

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="PnlData" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
      <Columns>
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Bln" HeaderText="Bln Test" SortExpression="Bln" />
      </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
  </div>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="select 'true' as bln from dual union select 'false' as bln from dual union select 'True' as bln from dual">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
  </form>
```

Comment: Already tried that. It still gives the same error as the DECODE function doesn't convert the data type to Boolean as Oracle *still* doesn't support the Boolean data type from DML.

Comment: The issue is not the return type from the db as the exception is of type FormatException and indicates the STRING is not a valid boolean (as opposed to a cast error).  Try "True"/"False" (capital T/F) in the decode.  The Convert class might be being used instead and it appears to be more restrictive with it's "TrueValue" and "FalseValue".  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3.aspx

Comment: Something else is happening here.  I've confirmed that this works without issue (see edited answer with example).  Please update your question with the query you are using.

Comment: OMG! It's working. My downfall was using the DECODE function directly on the view itself as appose to using it on the query behind the SqlDataSource. Thank you so much for shedding the light. This has been a tremendous headache for me, and I almost resorted to just displaying a text "yes" or "no" for that column.

Comment: This was my first question ever. Now... how in the heck do I mark your reply as the correct answer? Oh, never mind. I see the check mark now. Why didn't I notice that before I started typing this?

Comment: Even in a view I'd expect this to work but I'm glad you got it working.  And don't worry, we were a long way from resorting to "yes"/"no".  If we couldn't get this way to work we could have created a templated column where we would have had more control over the value or you could have set the control's value in the DataBound event in the code behind.

Comment: It's never easy to predict how things will go with programming. It sucks how one small detail that may seem totally irrelevant could make the code not working.